# Type H: illegal hex digit x

Tags: php, sql-server

I am doing a data conversion from one application to another application. One of the MSSQL table store documents such PDF and DOC as hex string. I have been asked to convert these hex string and write into files.

I have googled and found a site that suggested the following:

```
$hex    = file_get_contents('hex.txt');
file_put_contents('converted.pdf', pack('H*', $hex));
```

where hex.txt is extract of the data from the table. However, I am getting the error

> PHP Warning:  pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit x in ....

Below is an shorten version of the extracted hex string

> 0xEC5A09584CFBFB3F33A575A64D9B164EB750A.....

So now, I would like to know if it is possible to convert these hex string into binary and write it into a file. Thank you and hope someone can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 3):

`0x` just denotes the string as a hexadecimal number. Strip it and `pack()` the rest.

Comment: Thanks. That stops the error from appearing. However, its not making a valid PDF file. Anyone know how to convert hex string into PDF or DOC files?

Comment: @asyadiqin: Double-check the endianness and size of the file; in a data conversion, it is all too easy for something to go wrong there. Make a hex dump of the first few bytes of `converted.pdf`; it should start with `25 50 44 46`, in that order (`%PDF`). Compare the size of `converted.pdf` with the size of the data in the _original_ data source. Do not trust intermediate files; data may have been truncated during export.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pdf generation library for php:

- In the php library:
  https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdf.examples-basic.php
- External libraries:
  http://www.tcpdf.org/
  http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: Not really looking at a PDF library but more into converting a hex string and writing into a PDF file. The hex string was generated by a software called Front Desk which converted uploaded files into hex string and store it as a hex string. So wondering I can reverse the process and write it back into a file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$hexAsString = file_get_contents( 'hex.txt' );

// Just in case...
assert( '0x' == substr( $hexAsString, 0, 2 ));

// Skip first two chars
$hexDigits = substr( $hexAsString, 2, strlen( $hexAsString ) -2 );

file_put_contents( 'converted.pdf', pack('H*', $hexDigits));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you already posted the answer to your question in a comment:

> The hex string was generated by a software called Front Desk which
>   converted uploaded files into hex string and store it as a hex string.

Your best bet is to either find some kind of documentation on how Front Desk converts its files; or go the hard way and do some trial&error reverse-engineering by uploading some new simple test-files.

It might well be the system adds for instance some kind of checks/meta-data to the hex-string. Or does some kind of compression first (think ZIP).